# How to properly format the output of custom fields in the woocommerce order email

Tags: woocommerce

This all works - except that the email notification prints the ugly field name - not a label

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 $fields['billing']['billing_extra_adult_member'] = array(
'label'     => __('2nd Adult Member', 'woocommerce'),
'placeholder'   => _x('Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'required'  => false,
'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
'clear'     => true
 );
 $fields['billing']['billing_extra_child_member1'] = array(
'label'     => __('1st Child Member', 'woocommerce'),
'placeholder'   => _x('Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'required'  => false,
'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
'clear'     => true
 );

return $fields;
}
/**
* Add the field to order
**/
function your_custom_field_function_name($order){
echo "<p><strong>Extra adult member:</strong> " .             
$order->order_custom_fields['_billing_extra_adult_member'][0] . "</p>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address',    
'your_custom_field_function_name', 10, 1 );

/**
* Add the field to order emails
**/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys',    
'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
$keys[] = '_billing_extra_adult_member';
return $keys;
}
```

Email notification contains:

_billing_extra_adult_member: Joe Snow

I want to make this:

Extra adult member: Joe snow

anyone help ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$keys['Extra adult member'] = '_billing_extra_adult_member';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider adding some explanation to answers in the future to make them a little more helpful.